# Is it possible to model the connection of pre-cast and site cast concrete beam on FEA software such as Ansys?

Tags: structural-engineering, strength, ansys

I'm looking for a way to compare the joint strength of beam-to-column connections of pre-cast and site cast concrete. Is it possible to do this on a FEA software?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible. You will probably need to describe volumetric change during curing, which should be possible using element "[swelling](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0950061822032500)" feature. As a result, there will be different prestress fields. Since you have more control in case of pre-casting, I would guess it has a potential to have more advantageous residual stress field than site cast.